# Formas de Cast com interface

Tags: c#, .net

queria saber quais são as possibilidades (porém qual a mais indicada) para fazer um cast com interface.

```
public class ClasseTeste1 : IMinhaInterface { ... }
public class ClasseTeste2 : IMinhaInterface { ... }
```

Veja no exemplo que estou utilizando ela na passagem de parâmetro no método.

```
public void MeuMetodo(IMinhaInterface parametro)
{
    var objetodaClasse1 = (ClasseTeste1)parametro;
    var objetodaClasse2 = (ClasseTeste2)parametro;

    //Mas qual classe seria a que veio pelo parâmetro?
    ...
}
```

> Neste caso, no lugar de colocar o tipo da classe, gostaria de obter o
>   tipo pelo objeto. via algum tipo de gettype por exemplo.

Veja como eu imagino que seria

```
public void MeuMetodo(IMinhaInterface parametro)
    {
        var objetodaClasse = (parametro.gettype())parametro;

        ...
    }
```

Porém, quero deixar a definição da classe de acordo com o parâmetro. Então eu precisaria de ter algum GetType para saber qual será a classe a ser instanciada.

O que mais me indicam neste cenário?

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja. Talvez não seja possível ou não seja o mais indicado. Tente mostrar com código o que faria.

Comment: Quero fazer um cast para a classe. vou editar a pergunta para tentar ser mais claro.

Comment: @BrunoHeringer, dá uma olhada se a resposta te atende. Só um detalhe, dentro do método, você só vai utilizar o que é específico da interface, correto? Porque se for utilizar métodos específicos de cada implementação, então a abordagem deve ser outra.

Comment: Ainda não ficou claro porque precisa de deste *cast*, alguma coisa me diz que não precisa. Coloque mais alguma coisa no código que indique o motivo de precisar do *cast*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode deixar para o compilador resolver este cast para você. Isto pode ser facilmente realizado com a utilização de uma [restrição de parâmetros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d5x73970.aspx). basta criar o método desta forma:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ClasseTeste1 teste1 = new ClasseTeste1();
        ClasseTeste2 teste2 = new ClasseTeste2();

        MeuMetodoDinamico(teste1);
        MeuMetodoDinamico(teste2);
    }

    // Aqui está a mágica do negócio, você exige que o parâmetro chamado 
    // seja um objeto que implementa a interface IMinhaInterface
    public static void MeuMetodoDinamico<T>(T parametro) where T : IMinhaInterface
    {
        parametro.MeuMetodo();
    }
}

public interface IMinhaInterface {
    void MeuMetodo();
}

public class ClasseTeste1 : IMinhaInterface {
    public void MeuMetodo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Classe Teste 1");        
    }
}

public class ClasseTeste2 : IMinhaInterface {
    public void MeuMetodo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Classe Teste 2");
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RsEAzr).

Comment: Sem o genérico também funciona :) https://dotnetfiddle.net/XCcmdJ

Comment: Eu não entendi direito qual o problema que a resposta soluciona. Teria como elaborar qual seria a vantagem disso que foi respondido em relação a simplesmente fazer o que o @bigown pos de exemplo no dotnetfiddle no comentário anterior, só pra gente entender melhor?.

Comment: Qual o propósito de usar generics nessa resposta?

Comment: Sem o generics também funciona, na realidade a questão está um pouco confusa, quando eu respondi, estava saindo e nem reparei no propósito da questão. Provavelmente existe algum problema de estrutura no código, pois se precisa de dar cast no objeto, não faz sentido o uso da interface.